# SystemTray Icon Coordinate - C#

Tags: c#

How can I get those coordinates of Application Icon which is find in the Window taskbar's status area (a.k.a. System Tray) in C#?

Comment: It's a "Notification Icon", in case that makes your searching easier.

Comment: Take getting a mouse event from the NotifyIcon as a sure sign that the user is pretty close to that icon.  The icon center is within +/- 8 pixels from Cursor.Position, close enough for anything like a context menu.

Comment: @Hans Passant-thanks for your comment.As you said,how can I do that?So is there a sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this by fair means. No such API exists. There are, of course, various hacky ways to find it out, but I won't get into that.

Normally what you want to do is show a menu in response to a click on the tray icon. The message that Windows sends you when this happens contains the cursor coordinates where the click occurred.  That's usually enough information to show whatever it is you show in response to the click.

In C# this translates to reading the coordinates out of the `MouseEventArgs` in [`NotifyIcon.MouseUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.mouseup.aspx).

Comment: is is me or `various hacky ways` is way to vague?

Comment: @Felipe I don't want to advocate such nefarious activities.

Comment: @David Heffernan-First of all,thanks for your interesting.Is it possible to do it with Shell_WotifyWindow  or NotifyWindowData methods?

Comment: there are no apis for this in windows